# ¿ Alguien me podría explicar como es el modelo entidad relación de la siguiente imagen con su respectiva cardinalidad?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, modelorelacional

[image: base de datos creada en PhpMyAdmin]

alguien que me instruya en el modelo entidad relación de la siguiente imagen, tampoco entiendo porque algunas llaves primarias pasaron a hacer llaves foranes en otras tablas y los campos de create, update y delete en cada tabla, se lo agradecería

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que puedo ver el tipo de cardinalidad que tendrías en un ER es de 1-M *uno a muchos*

- Las llaves primarias que pasaron a ser foráneas en otras tablas lo hicieron para poder crear la relación entre tablas.

Ahora, no te puedo explicar con exactitud el modelo entidad relación ya que no tengo conocimiento de las reglas del negocio que requiere la base de datos, pero lo que puedo suponer es:

- Las tablas fuertes serían cancionesusuarios, configuracions, historialreproduccions debido a que no dependen funcionalmente de otra tabla y la tabla débil usuarios porque depende funcionalmente de las fuertes.

Noto que la tabla no está normalizada.
Si estás diseñándola tu, normalízala hasta la 3FN como mínimo para evitar redundancias.
Si mantienes este esquema entonces la tabla usuarios tendrá 1 registro repetido con los datos del usuario por cada canción que suba. Lo mismo ocurriría si el usuario es capaz de tener varias configuraciones e historial de reproducciones.
Para solucionar esos detalles lo que yo haría es:

1. corregir la relación que tienes entre el id de la tabla cancionesusuarios y cancionesusuarios_id de la tabla usuarios.
2. La definiría entre el id de la tabla usuarios y usuarios_id de la tabla cancionesusuarios.
3. Seguidamente elimino el campo cancionesusuarios_id de la tabla usuarios.

Siguiendo los pasos 1, 2 y 3 solucionas el detalle de registros duplicados entre la tabla cancionesusuarios y usuarios.

Comment: Para solucionar el problema de redundancia de las otras tablas solo sigue los pasos 1, 2 y 3 substituyendo las tablas y las columnas

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder. Lo que exactamente busco con esto es hacer una Aplicación - clon de SoundCloud o algo similar. Apenas estoy comenzando en el mundo de la programación alguna recomendaciones que me puedas dar?

Comment: De nada! Supongo que ya has avanzado desde el último post, pero te recomendaría que hagas la planificación de la BD muy bien, ya que si no está afinada retrasará el desarrollo de la appAdemás recomendaría que uses procedimientos almacenados, triggers, funciones, etc cuando puedas hacerlo, ya que eso hará a tu app mucho más fluida ya que esas secciones las ejecutará tu servidor. Eso viene de perlas ya que no todos tienen los mejores dispositivos o el mejor internet así reduces la carga del lado del cliente, y por la parte del servidor no afecta ya que los SGBD optimizan las consultas frecuentes